# How to generate number sequence 1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,

Tags: r, numbers, sequence

I want to generate an alternating sequence, to enter them into a dataframe in R. Always two of each element (in my case: 2x daughter, 2x mother). In my specific example, I use the indices 1,2,5,6,9,10, etc.

My desired output is a dataframe of the form:

```
df <- data.frame(values=c(sample(1:8)), relation=c("daughter", "daughter", "mother", "mother", "daughter", "daughter", "mother", "mother"))
df

  values relation
1      4 daughter
2      3 daughter
3      2   mother
4      8   mother
5      1 daughter
6      5 daughter
7      6   mother
8      7   mother
```

I can find the correct index to replace the initial entries with this:

```
daughter_id <- sort(c(seq(1,20, 4), seq(2,20, 4)))
mother_id <- sort(c(seq(3,20, 4), seq(4,20, 4)))
```

It works and allows me to enter my desired values:

```
df[daughter_id ,"relation"] <- "daughter"
df[mother_id,"relation"] <- "mother"
```

But is there a simpler solution?
And is there a solution that directly inserts certain values n times?

Comment: `?rep` is your friend for this I think, so you could use `rep(c("daughter", "mother"),  each = 2, times = 30)`

Comment: Now I feel dumb, thank you! It solves my specific case and the similar ones that I will likely run into. I'd accept your answer if it was a reply instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
c(rbind(1+4*(1:k), 2+4*(1:k)))
```

basically taking advantage of how R stores matrices (column-major vectors)

or perhaps:

```
sweep(4L*rbind(1:k, 1:k), 1L, 1:2, '+')
```